# Output seen only after the program has finished execution in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am building a simulator for some biological processes. I have used an ArrayList which contains huge number of elements. I have called some 3-4 functions in loop (Which takes considerable time to return result) which operate and manipulate this ArrayList. At the end of each loop i have displayed the result of this iteration in jTable. Problem I am facing is that at the end of each loop I should see a row added but i am seeing the whole output (i.e Whole ) only after the program has finished executing.

The following code helps visualize my code's architecture

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++){
process1(s);
process2(s);
.
.
.
processn(s);
displaySummaryOfArraylistInJTableForThisIteration(s);
}
```

Comment: Are you using threads?

Comment: can you explain or show what is "displaySummaryOfArraylistInJTableForThisIteration(s);" (in terms of functionality, also I think that you are experiencing a concurrency issue

Comment: I don't have concept of threads. Please send me some links of tutorials so i can understand threads and solve this problem.

Comment: @user2718320 You can find a super sweet introductory SwingWorker tutorial here: http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/

Comment: You really need to change the method name: `displaySummaryOfArraylistInJTableForThisIteration`

Comment: @MarounMaroun the method name i have given here is just figure of speech.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are setting the new table model everytime in `displaySummaryOfArraylistInJTableForThisIteration(s);` you still have to use threads for this process so the info can be displayed every time that you set the info in the table, and not at the end of the process, check [concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) in swing

So you are looking for something like this

```
private class YourTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       // refresh the table data

    }
}

 YourTask task = new YourTask();
        Thread newThread = new Thread(task);
        newThread.start();
```

First you need to define a class that implements `Runnable` and you will override the run method so this method can perform your desired behavior, I recommend that you declare your class as a inner class so you can take advantage of class global fields. After that you will create an instance of `YourClass` and other one from `Thread` sending the instance from `YourClass` to the constructor. and finally just use the `start();` method from the `Thread` class. To conceptual explanation you can visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29).

Comment: displaySummaryOfArraylistInJTableForThisIteration(s); calls the following method::

DefaultTableModel model = 
DefaultTableModel)simulationStatisticsTable.getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[]{time,(SimulationStatistics.a+SimulationStatistics.b),SimulationStatistics.c});

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the OP doing work on the Event Dispatch thread.

Comment: check my answer again @user2718320

Answer (score 1):

If you run in [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) then the gui is gonna freeze until finish.
You can use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) here is an example i really like [Swing Worker Example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

Example:

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground() throws Exception {
       //here you make process the mail
       String partialResults= process1();
       publish(partialResults);
       String partialResults= process2();
       publish(partialResults);
       .
       .


    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        //this is executed in the EDT
        addToJTable(chunks);
    }
}
```